# Mysql query to get lowest field values from multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to pull up 1 record from table t1 for each id in table t2 based on the 't1.sort' field, the following code works well until a user deletes the first record then t1.sort='1' returns nothing, how do I select where 't1.sort' is the lowest for each id so I still get one record each?
Sorry I was lost just wording the question.....
Thanks in advance for any help.

```
SELECT
    t1.foreign_id,
    t1.small_path,
    t2.title
FROM
    stivagallery_plugin_gallery t1,
    stivagallery_galleries t2
WHERE t1.foreign_id = t2.id
AND t1.sort= '1'
ORDER BY t1.foreign_id
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0):

You could renumber the rows within the query with `dense_rank()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t1.foreign_id, t1.small_path, t2.title,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t1.sort) rn
    FROM stivagallery_plugin_gallery t1
    INNER JOIN stivagallery_galleries t2 ON t1.foreign_id = t2.id
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY foreign_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I tried your code but just generated 0 results. I think I'm only on mysql 5.6, hosted server so not my option on version.